# Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll When trying to delete empty folders

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program that scans for empty folders and deletes them. I have a question about my code. When I run the debugger it throws an error when it's going to scan for folders and the error it throws is. 'System.ArgumentException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll. I cannot really find anything online about this error. Here's my code.

```
Private Sub RemoveEmptyFolders(ByVal path As String)

    Try
        For Each fname As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Dir)
            Dim fn As New DirectoryInfo(fname)
            If fn.GetFiles.Length = 0 AndAlso fn.GetDirectories.Length = 0 Then
                fn.Delete()
                Console.WriteLine("Deleted " + fname + "!")
            End If
        Next
        For Each subdir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Dir)
            RemoveEmptyFolders(subdir)
        Next
    Catch
    End Try

End Sub
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error in the debugger and I have no idea what I'm missing here. The code looks just about right from my perspective. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: If you're getting an `ArgumentException` then obviously there's an issue with a method argument. What line is the exception thrown on? What is the error message? What is the value of each argument you're passing to the method call when the exception is thrown?

Comment: By the way, you don;t have to call both `GetFiles` and `GetDirectories`. `GetFileSystemInfos` gets both files and folders.

Comment: Also, why have two loops? Why not move the contents of the second loop into an `Else` block in the first loop?

Answer (score 0):

when you call the second loop the directory is already been deleted and that is why you are getting the System.ArgumentException. if you want to use two loops, put the second inside the first and execute the fn.Delete() after you removed all the sub-directories.